# How to show always days on datepicker when is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.date" id="dateStart">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#dateStart").datetimepicker({
    format: 'ddd, D MMMM YYYY',
    showTodayButton: true
    });
</script>
```

What I want to achieve is that everytime I close the picker and reopen it I'll always have the days picker. 
Right now If I'm in the "datepicker-months" and click outside, the picker will close and if I reopen it it will show the months view again, but I want the days one.

I tried with:

```
on('dp.show', function(e) {
    $(".datepicker-days").show();
    $(".datepicker-months").hide();
    $(".datepicker-years").hide();
    $(".datepicker-decades").hide();
});
```

This ways looks like it's working: if I close it during months view and reopen it I'll get the days datepicker, but if from here I click on the month again I'll get the datepicker-years..

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xrqkyypd/51/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty much straightforward using [events](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/) and [`viewMode`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#viewmode) function.

You only must check that when the picker get hide then you reset his `viewMode` to which ever you want, in this case the days view.

```
$('#myDatepicker').on('dp.hide', function(e) {
  $('#myDatepicker').data("DateTimePicker").viewMode('days')
});
```

Answer (score -1):

According with documentation, you can set like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:130px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker9'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({
                viewMode: 'years' //days, weeks etc
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

For more details check [view mode](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#view-mode)

Comment: Doesn't work with this, it seems viewMode only applies for the first time the datepicker is shown, if you close it and reopen it it will show the last "viewMode" again..

Comment: Make a plunkr with all you have, and I will solve it.